# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 224, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code:

```
model = DeepFace.build_model('VGG-Face')
print(img.shape) # (224, 224, 3)
print(model.input_shape) # (None, 224, 224, 3)
representation = model.predict(img)
print(representation)
return representation
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(32, 224, 3)
```

So, how can I reshape img to (None, 224, 224, 3)

Thanks

Comment: Add batch dimension by: `np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)`, then predict.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @frightera the method for prepping a tensor for prediction is `np.expand_dims()`.

Let's say our model looks like this

```
Model: "model_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential (Sequential)      (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
vggface_resnet50 (Functional (None, 1, 1, 2048)        23561152  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           (None, 8)                 16392     
=================================================================
Total params: 23,577,544
Trainable params: 16,392
Non-trainable params: 23,561,152
_________________________________________________________________
```

And let's say this is VGGFace, so we need to ensure that the image is 224x224x3, AND we need to add this 'batch' dimension.  (let's say we've loaded our image with `PIL.Image.open()`)

We can prep images with:

```
def prepPred(someImage, resizeTarget=224):
    """Prepare Image for prediction"""
    someImage = someImage.resize((resizeTarget, 
                                  resizeTarget), 
                                 pillowImageLoader.BILINEAR)
    # Convert image to array
    imageArray = np.array(someImage)
    # add the batch dimension and return
    return np.expand_dims(imageArray, axis=0)
```

Models always expect batches - when you train, you provide batches, and when you predict, you have to provide batches - in this case, it's just a 'batch' of 1.